# Google App Engine Java, cannot access localhost!

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

I am starting to develop my first GAE app and just installed the eclipse plugin.

The problem is that I cannot even run the sample apps already included with the plugin.

After compiling, the log reads that the server is running but when I point my browser to that address it fails to connect.

I have verified that the problem is not with localhost, as I can connect to it if I run tomcat, or other servers.

The problem is specific to eclipse and GAE.

Any ideas?

Comment: when you run the app locally, the eclipse console tells you at which port the server is listening. Have you tried pointing your browser to http://localhost:PPPP ?  (PPPP=the port number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now confirmed this is a know issue with the newest Java update for mac.

The browser cannot connect to localhost because there is no one listening there, the issue causes the server to crash just after it has started running.

You can read more about the issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4712&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log).

For now, the solution is to revert back to the last version of Java for mac (.22).

Hopefully Google and Apple will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something is blocking the port your server should run on.

e.g. skype wants to run on port 80 in default settings

on windows try "netstat -a -n"

Comment: I heard a rumor that they ported "netstat -a -n" to unix-based systems now as well.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this a cross-domain security issue?  Perhaps the browser is pointing to the web page at port 80 and the page you get back tries to do a cross domain access to the GAE services on port 8080?  That will cause a failure.  Or do you have the app on 8080 also serving out the web page?

The best way to figure out the problem is to install a debugger add-on in your browser.  I suggest Firebug for Firefox or Web Developer for Chrome.  Or just look on the javascript console for your browser.